# Huge Salary Reduction

Tags: salary

My current employer is reducing my salary by 40K and only offering me a position that I am not qualified to do and will fail.  They have not provided me a new job description or transition plan.  I have never been written up but have received glowing emails from the owner and as well as 2 raises.  This is all being done by a new COO that has been with the company only for a few months.

Should I seek legal help? I feel they are wanting me to quit.

Comment: For this sort of question, country and, where relevant, state can make a big difference. For example, 40K of what currency? Are you in an at-will employment jurisdiction, or one where there are limitations on firing?

Comment: Anyone else being moved or salary cut that you know of?  Is your old job going away?

Comment: No one else is receiving a pay cut - just me.  I was told it was going away however I received a copy of an email that went to the staff advising they were looking for someone new.

Comment: The COO wants you gone and probably is trying to avoid paying unemployment.

Comment: Frankly I do not believe this is true. I.e You got a new job in the same company at there whim. The caretaker is looking worried

Comment: Off topic - Rather than explaining why your situation is terrible, or why your boss/coworker makes you unhappy, explain what you want to do to make it better.  Voting to close.

Comment: **Where are you from?** Closing as unclear until we get a country. Note that legal advice beyond "this is generally illegal/legal" is off-topic here.

Comment: Sounds like constructive dismissal to me, but IANAL.

Comment: @PeterK.: You don't have to be a lawyer to recognise a constructive dismissal. This one seems a very clear case (unless the salary is reduced from 600K to 560K; that would be less clear). Of course you want a lawyer to find the best way to handle it, which will very much depend on the country. It's roughly the same as just being fired and just as legal or illegal, depending on the country.

Comment: Been there. This is a clear case of constructive dismissal. They are trying to make you resign so they can avoid paying you severance. Consult a lawyer immediately.

Comment: No idea why this was closed. It's an excellent question and  with a real answer. Even if you think the answer is "there is nothing you can do" you shouldn't close the question for that reason.

Comment: @gnasher729 yes, that's the point of the IANAL: it's clearly constructive dismissal, but only a lawyer can say what the best thing to do about it for the OP's situation, locality, and temperament.

Comment: And print out a copy of that email where they re-advertised your old job. And if you have anything in writing that says you were moved because the old job was going away.

Answer (score 3):

No. Pursuing legal action is expensive and uncertain.

You should search for a new job immediately.

Comment: "*Pursuing legal action is expensive and uncertain*". Not everywhere. OP needs to specify a country before you can make this claim.

Comment: @Lilienthal: Name a country where this is not the case.

Comment: The UK's employment tribunals come to mind. Several European countries have simplified and affordable procedures for disputing hostile actions designed to force out employees without paying severance and/or unemployment benefits. Your claim is too absolute for an international site. Legal action is often a bad idea but can be the best option in some situations and that evaluation needs to be made on a case-by-case basis. That's why your advice is potentially harmful and why such questions are off-topic.

Comment: @JimG. In germany, doing something like this is a very quick way as an employer to get sued out of business. By the feds, on behalf of the employee.

Comment: Taking a 40K hit is very expensive also.  Evaluating whether to  pursue legal actions is relative to the loss and could be worthwhile in this case.

Comment: This opens the company up to an expensive legal action in virtually every industrialized country except the US. And in the US they wouldn't bother ,since they can just fire the OP anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Find a new job, you are being forced out. And it appears there is some malice behind it. It's better to resign than to fail and give them a reason to fire you for incompetence. This is the usual reason for throwing an employee into an job they cannot do.

Seek legal advice if you want, 40k is a LOT of money and you may have grounds. But you won't get that legal advice here, and couldn't trust it if you did.

Answer (score -2):

Sure appears the COO wants you gone and probably not much you can do about it.

Polish your resume and get it out there.

Take notes.  When you get the job description put in writing the training you require to perform the job.  If they are doing this to try and fire you with cause then you can say but you have not provided training.  There is still probably not much you can do about it but what can it hurt?

This is just odd. I would ask your boss and / or trusted co-workers what is really going on.

Comment: Down vote care to comment?

Comment: Yeah, the down votes are just odd.  Nothing unreasonable in your answer.  It is seriously time for OP to move on.  The handwriting is on the wall, floor, ceiling, and pasted on the refrigerator door.